# Can Gtk widgets be imported into Gtk#

Tags: gtk, gtk#, gtksourceview

I'm trying to use the `GtkSourceView` into a Gtk# project, as the `TextView` is simply horrid.

How can I do that?

There's a GtkSourceView-sharp but it's outrageously dated and doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer you about all the widgets, but about GtkSourceView, I used it a couple of days ago and it works just fine, even with Glade. The Nuget package I used is [GtkSourceSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GtkSourceSharp), which version is 3.24.24.34, like the latest GtkSharp available.
If you need to use it with Glade just remember do a dummy declaration before loading the .glade file that contains the actual widget:

```
        var tmp = new SourceView();
        Builder builder = new Builder(null, "file.glade", null);
```